# How to map state with complex objects in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I have a fairly simple problem I want to use the map function where it applies the function to every element in the list. Now the problem is that I have a State type which is defined as follows:

```
newtype State a = State (Stack a)
   deriving (Show)
data Stack a = Active [a] | Inactive [a]
   deriving (Show)
```

So the State has a Stack inside of it and the list that im trying to map is inside of the Stack. Now this is the map function I'm trying to write:

```
mapState :: (Eq b) => (a -> b) -> State a -> State b
mapState f (State(Inactive (h:t))) = f h : mapState f (State(Inactive t))
```

Which obviously would not work because mapState returns a State and f h returns an element. And I also tried:

```
mapState f (State(Inactive (f h : t)))
```

Which would give me the following errors:

```
Couldn't match type ‘a’ with ‘b’
  Expected: [b]
    Actual: [a]
```

Now I don't think

```
mapState f (State(Inactive (f h : t)))
```

Is the right way to go about the problem, because it would result in infinite recursion anyways. So what is the solution for this?

Comment: Enable [`{-# Language DeriveFunctor #-}`](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/deriving_extra.html#extension-DeriveFunctor) (and [`DerivingStrategies`](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/deriving_strategies.html)) and write `deriving stock Functor`.

Answer (score 3):

You perform a mapping on the elements of the `State`, so:

```
mapState :: (a -> b) -> State a -> State b
mapState f (State (Active xs)) = State (Active (fmap f xs))
mapState f (State (Inactive xs)) = State (Inactive (fmap f xs))
```

Usually you do this by making this an instance of a `Functor`:

```
instance Functor State where
    fmap f (State (Active xs)) = State (Active (fmap f xs))
    fmap f (State (Inactive xs)) = State (Inactive (fmap f xs))
```

Comment: What is State s xs? Is it the same as State(Inactive (h:t)) Because it will not work if I did State s xs